# A button next to an EditText

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, android-edittext, android-button

In Xamarin, I have a Layout with an EditText that I can enter text into to search for a Location.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need a button next to the `EditText` that I can click on to clear the `ListView` that is displayed.

How would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Can the button be part of the control?

Have a look at this link: http://components.xamarin.com/

The "Search Components" EditText has a search icon, and if text is entered this icon changes to a x.

Is this easy to code?

Comment: Give some feed back to that people if these answer helpful to you or not??

Comment: Means you need to like make edittext as search bar view?

Comment: Can you explain how to do that please?

Comment: you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dip" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="Find..." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OR ANOTHER IS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dip" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:hint="Find..." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Find..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you would like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mapWithOverlay" >
</ListView>
```

Use of Image to clear

```
btn_clear=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
btn_clear.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner){
   //do clear your edittext
)};
```

Comment: Just copy and past it in Layout